# Kong based rate limiting for API-KEYS in header

Tags: rate-limiting, kong, kong-plugin

I have been exploring rate-limit plugin option of Kong and there are two ways in which we can configure limit by header.

1. rate-limit by header, so a request through a single API key can only be sent only x times in an hour/minute. (active users)
2. rate-limit for a specific API key, so that requests do not come through their API keys. (would want the rate-limit to be 0 in this case - non active users)\

Is there a way to combine these and use in Kong. I don't want to set up consumers and consumers group and set rate limiting through this way. Can it be done through simple configuration?

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: rate-limiting-example
config: 
  second: 5
  hour: 10000
  policy: local
plugin: rate-limiting
```

Comment: What is the reason for not using consumers to identify the caller and applying rate-limiting to the authenticated users? If the user lacks API key the request will be stop anyway.

Comment: I did this one year ago, you can rate limite per header https://github.com/ManoManoTech/kong-plugin-mm-rate-limiting